# Zend Framework - Add Functionality To $this

Tags: zend-framework

In Zend Framework, is it possible to add functionality to the $this object used within the controller?

I'm trying to create an API, defined by class files stored in a seperate folder. So would love to be able to go:

```
$userDetails = $this->api->user()->getDetails();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a reference to the object instance so you just need to add methods and properties to the class in question. For example:

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
   protected $api = null;

   public function init()
   {
      $this->api = new ApiClass();
   }

   public function indexAction()
   {
      $this->api->user()->details();
   }


}
```

Of course this probably isnt the best way to go about it. I would probably put the api as a bootstrap resource and in that case youd do:

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

   public function indexAction()
   {
      $this->getApi()->user()->details();
   }

   public function getApi()
   {
      return $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->api;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is probably the best answer that suits my question. I'm happy to make a Bootstrap resource, but how do I make a class Autoloader as it were? So I could invoke $this->api->className->Method without having to create an api.php file that insantiated all the classes and methods? There has to be a clever/automated way surely?

Comment: Well you cold create your own infrastructure on the API class or oyu could leverage [`Zend_Loader_PluginLoader`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.pluginloader.html) but you would still need to create all the classes that the API is going to use. This should really be a new question as its really completely separate from this one.

Comment: Thanks, I don't suppose you know of any links to any examples (other than the one you included)? I have all the classes already created in an /application/api folder.

Comment: I havent seen any tutorials for using the plugin loader, but you should be able to implement by looking at the code in that class plus something that uses it like `Zend_View` (used to load view helpers).

Comment: Thanks for your help and time, however I've decided against this approach. The only maintainable way to get this to work is to create an api.php file with magic getters and setters, which are 'heavy' and slow. So I decided not to bother. Instead, I've setup a static approache so I simply type Api_Admin_Users::create($params)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new folder in your library where you can save your own classes. E.g.: `Sjwdavies`
Create a new file: `Sjwdavies/Controller/Action.php`

```
class Sjwdavies_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public $api;
}
```

Your controllers now have to extend this class:

```
class IndexController extends Sjwdavies_Controller_Action
{
    public $api;
}
```

Be sure to include the library path in your application.ini:

```
includePaths.library    = APPLICATION_PATH "../../library"
```